# delete element from document in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongoDB where all the documents have this structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("522489bdfc346a1464659634"),
"Flash_point" : 105,
"Boiling_point" : 112,
"Melting_point" : 41}
```

I have no idea how to delete "Flash_point"-element from a document in C#

Afterwards, the document should look like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("522489bdfc346a1464659634"),
"Boiling_point" : 112,
"Melting_point" : 41}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want to delete all instances of `Flash_point` in your collection, or just in certain cases?

Comment: in certain cases, i have a few _id's where i want to delete it. At the moment, those _id's are in a list

Comment: @neoistheone this isn't a dupe of that question.  this question refers to removing a single attribute vs a whole document

Comment: @neoistheone : No, my problem is about removing a element from a document. Not removing a document from a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on the web for a while, I found it myself.

For those who want to know my solution:

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < idlist.Count ; j++)
{
    var queryDeleteValue = new QueryDocument("_id", idlist[j]);
    var update = Update.Unset("Flash_point");
    collectionInput.Update(queryDeleteValue, update);
}
```

So, first of all, I have a query-variable that selects the right document. Then I make an update variable where I unset the element 'Flash_point'.
The last step is to do the actual update (with the parameters 'queryDeleteValue' and 'update').